# Hello World Rainbow

Tags: code-golf, hello-world

Dealing with colors in non-markup languages often complicates things.
I would like to see some variations of how color is used in different languages.

The object of this competition is to output 'Hello World' in the seven colors of the rainbow.

According to Wikipedia, these are the 7 colors.

```
Red      #FF0000 (RGB: 255, 0, 0)
Orange   #FF7F00 (RGB: 255, 127, 0)
Yellow   #FFFF00 (RGB: 255, 255, 0)
Green    #00FF00 (RGB: 0, 255, 0)
Blue     #0000FF (RGB: 0, 0, 255)
Indigo   #6600FF (RGB: 111, 0, 255)
Violet   #8B00FF (RGB: 143, 0, 255)
```

**The rules**

1. The program must output 'Hello World'. (Doesn't necessarily need to be text, but it must be distiguishable as 'Hello World')
2. Each letter must be a different color.
3. The colors can be in any order.
4. You must use each of the seven colors at least once. (You may use more than the given colors)
5. No use of markup languages *in any case*.

**The winner is whoever has the lowest amount of characters AND follows the rules**

**Bonus -1 character if it is written in [DART](http://www.dartlang.org/)**

I will pick the winner on Jan 11 (if I remember ;D).

Good luck

### WINNER(s)

I made a mistake D:, updated winners.

1st.
[stranac - Python, 60 chars](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4564/3473)

2nd.
[Ilmari - Karonen Perl + GD, 146 chars](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4531/3473)

Shortest length with all rules adhered to.

[Brownie points to JiminP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4563/3473) for the DART answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Python, 60 chars

Now using 7 colors, and the "correct" ones.
Uses ansi escape sequences. The underscore is there just so it's not an invisible space.
This version prints some extra spaces, because of the way python's print works, but those spaces save quite a few chars, so I'm fine with them being there.

```
for p in zip(range(7)*2,'Hello_World'):print'\033[3%im%s'%p,
```

And a screenshot, as required by MrZander:
[image]

Comment: Have I made an error? 
Please post a screenshot proving that you used all colors properly.
"8 Colors from black to white" doesn't sound like it used the 7 required colors.

Comment: @MrZander: I have updated my answer, and hope it now pleases you. Btw, are you sure the 6th color you provided is correct? It is pretty much the same as the 7th.

Comment: Took it straight off Wikipedia... I'm no color expert haha.

Comment: This relies on a custom palette to work. For example, the `H` is printed using the escape code for black, so it's not visible on most terminals.

Answer (score 12):

### Mathematica

```
ImageMultiply[ColorNegate[Graphics[Text[Style["Hello World",30]],ImageSize->190]],ColorData["Rainbow","Image"]]
```

I know, I know, it doesn't comply with the rules.. but I had to try playing with Mathematica's image processing functions.

Screenshot:

[image: Hello World!!!!!!!]

Answer (score 10):

### Haskell, 88 characters

```
f(c,n)=putStr$"\27["++show n++"m"++[c]
main=mapM_ f$zip"Hello World\n"$35:cycle[31..36]
```

[image: Screenshot]

Note that this uses ANSI terminal colors, of which there are only 6 and they might not match the exact ones given (it depends on terminal settings), so I'm bending the rules a little here.

**Slightly longer version with almost correct colors, 107 characters**

This version uses xterm colors instead of ANSI ones. This does not rely on any custom palettes, and uses the closest colors I could find in the 256-color xterm palette.

```
f(c,n)=putStr$"\27[38;5;"++show n++"m"++[c]
main=mapM_ f$zip"Hello World\n"$cycle[196,208,226,46,21,57,93]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

### Perl -> ANSI terminal, 53 chars

```
s//Hello World/;s/./\e[3${[5,(1..6)x2]}[pos]m$&/g;say
```

This produces the exact same output as [Hammar's Haskell solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4529/3191).  It uses `say`, so needs perl 5.10+ and the `-M5.010` (or `-E`) switch.  For older perls, replace `say` with `print`.  A trivial one-character reduction could be achieved by replacing `\e` with a literal ESC character, but that would make the code much harder to read and edit.

**Edit:** Added two chars to match Hammar's output exactly, and to actually show all six possible terminal colors.  (In the earlier version, the only character printed in color 6 = cyan was the space.)

Screenshot:

[image: Hello World]

---

**Edit 2:** If [using a custom terminal palette](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4564) (and an underscore for the space) is allowed, then I can easily reproduce the exact colors given in the spec with just 50 chars:

```
$_=Hello_World;s/./\e[3${[(0..6)x2]}[pos]m$&/g;say
```

Screenshot:

[image: Hello_World]

Comment: [Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiMDAwMDAwMDA6IDczMmYgMmY0OCA2NTZjIDZjNmYgMjA1NyA2ZjcyIDZjNjQgMmYzYiAgcy8vSGVsbG8gV29ybGQvO1xuMDAwMDAwMTA6IDczMmYgMmUyZiAxYjViIDMzMjQgN2I1YiAzNTJjIDI4MzEgMmUyZSAgcy8uLy5bMyR7WzUsKDEuLlxuMDAwMDAwMjA6IDM2MjkgNzgzMiA1ZDdkIDViNzAgNmY3MyA1ZDZkIDI0MjYgMmY2NyAgNil4Ml19W3Bvc11tJCYvZ1xuMDAwMDAwMzA6IDNiNzMgNjE3OSAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgO3NheSIsImFyZ3MiOiItTTUuMTAuMCJ9) (Includes a 1-byte saving for literal Esc!

Answer (score 7):

### Python, 261 chars

```
C=((255,0,0),(255,127,0),(255,255,0),(0,255,0),(0,0,255),(111,0,255),(143,0,255))
print'P3 67 5 255'
for i in range(335):print'%d %d %d'%(C+C[2:])[i%67/6]if 0x4f7c938a00e7df7d12208a8aa0220820a34413d154044105f7e8828a28808820828cf04f39100e0417d1>>i&1 else'0 0 0'
```

Implements the spec exactly, generating a ppm image.  Here is the result, converted to gif and scaled up by a factor of 4:

[image]

Comment: Hehe, nice. Took me an embarrassingly long moment to understand.

Comment: `n=255;C=((n,0,0),(n,127,0),(n,n,0),(0,n,0),(0,0,n),(111,0,n),(143,0,n))`

Answer (score 3):

### Perl -> HTML, 99 chars

```
@c=(("00")x5,77,(ff)x5,77)x2;print"<font color=#",@c[$i+8,$i+4,$i++],">$_"for split//,"Hello World"
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Hello World]

The HTML probably won't pass any validators, but should be understood by just about all browsers.
This code doesn't produce the *exact* RGB colors you listed, but it does get very close.  Specifically, the colors of the letters are:

```
H  Red           #FF0000
e  Orange        #FF7700
l  Yellow        #FFFF00      
l  Chartreuse    #77FF00
o  Green         #00FF00
  (Spring green  #00FF77)
W  Cyan          #00FFFF
o  Sky blue      #0077FF
r  Blue          #0000FF
l  Indigo        #7700FF
d  Violet        #FF00FF
```

The output looks a lot nicer on a black background, but explicitly printing a `<body bgcolor=black>` would've cost me 28 extra characters.  You may adjust your browser settings to achieve the same effect instead. :-)

Comment: I may not have been specific enough with rule 5.
I didn't want to see markup used in conjunction with another language either.
 But in any case, very creative code.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl + GD, 146 chars

Per the comments to my [other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4530/3191), here's a solution that directly produces an image file using the GD library:

```
use GD'Simple;move{$m=new GD'Simple 70,12}2,12;s//Hello World/;s/./fgcolor$m(((0)x5,127,(255)x5,127)x2)[$i+8,$i+4,$i++];string$m$&/eg;print$m->png
```

And here's the output:

[image: Hello World]

Again, using a black background would look better, but would cost me 29 characters (`$m->bgcolor(0,0,0);$m->clear;`).

**Edit:** Figured out how to shave off 20 chars by (ab)using indirect object notation and a few other tweaks.  The new code emits a warning, but still runs fine.

Comment: That's more like it ;)

Comment: So far, this is the lowest character count that follows all the rules to the dot.

Answer (score 3):

Some cheating but solve the problem

### Bash + Ruby (needs `lolcat` gem)

```
echo Hello World | lolcat -p 0.25
```

[image: Rainbow Hello World]

Answer (score 3):

**Postscript <strike>155</strike> 143**

This relies on Ghostscript's ability to "figure-out" that Palatino is short for Palatino-Roman.

```
/h{c 1 1 sethsbcolor}def/c 0 def
200 400 moveto/Palatino 36 selectfont
h{32 ne{/c c .14 add dup 1 gt{1 sub}if def}if pop
h}(Hello World!)kshow
```

Comment: I suppose "Times" is shorter, but ... ugh.

Comment: Stole some of your ideas...

Answer (score 3):

Some different approaches to doing this with

**PostScript**

First: Shortest one (**89**):

```
9 9 moveto/Courier 9 selectfont
0{pop pop 
dup 1 1 sethsbcolor
.07 add}( Hello World)kshow
```

[image: Rendered result]

Un-golfed:

```
9 9 moveto
/Courier 9 selectfont
0                       % hue
{                       % hue c1 c2
  pop pop               % hue
  dup 1 1 sethsbcolor   % hue
  .07 add               % newHue
}( Hello World)kshow
```

This is continuously changing colour in x direction using the hsb color space. (Idea to use hsb colors and kshow are credited to luser droog - see his entry!) It does  not use the exact seven colors given by MrZander.

When restricting myself to MrZander's colors, I get there using **141** chars:

```
9 9 moveto/Courier 9 selectfont(H e*l4l4oI  WIosrsl{d~)dup
0 2 20{2 copy
1 add get 32 sub 166 div 1 1 sethsbcolor
1 getinterval show
dup}for
```

[image: Rendered result]

This encodes the hue value of MrZander's colors as one byte in the printable ASCII range. This byte is translated to a hue value in the range between 0 and 1 by subtracting 32 and dividing by 166. Each character of the "Hello World" string is followed by its encoded hue value.

Un-golfed:

```
9 9 moveto
/Courier 9 selectfont
(H e*l4l4oI  WIosrsl{d~)dup     % string string
0 2 20{                         % string string index
  2 copy                        % string string index string index
  1 add get                     % string string index hueChar
  32 sub 166 div                % string string index hueValue
  1 1 sethsbcolor               % string string index 
  1 getinterval                 % string substring
  show                          % string
  dup                           % string string
}for
```

**TODO**: Something isn't quite right with the colors.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 81 bytes

```bash
s="Hello World";for((i=0;i<11;i++));do printf "\e[$((RANDOM%9+31))m${s:i:1}";done
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v9hWySM1JydfITy/KCdFyTotv0hDI9PWwDrTxtDQOlNbW1PTOiVfoaAoM68kTUEpJjVaRUMjyNHPxd9X1VLb2FBTM1elutgq08qwVgmoMC/1/38A)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! What language is this?

Comment: Hi @RydwolfPrograms This is bash. Sorry I should've mentioned it

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @TheThonnu.  I just updated the answer.

Comment: @ValentinBajrami sorry, I didn't actually read the challenge before posting that comment. Since TIO doesn't support colours, the link is sort of useless, so you don't actually need it. Still a good first answer anyway.

Comment: It doesn't look like this uses the colours specified in the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

### Dart to HTML, <del>135</del> 134-1 = 133

`main(){for(var s="Hello World",i=0;i<11;print("<font color=#${'F00F60FB0FF06F00F00B606B00F60F90F'.substring(i*3,i*3+3)}>${s[i++]}"));}`

Is there any way to color texts without using markup language? I can't test canvases...

Comment: Oooo... +1 even with the HTML

Answer (score 1):

I know it says "no markup in any case", but I'd like to submit this CSS one in 468 characters:

```
<style>b{font-weight:normal}i{font-style:normal}u{text-decoration:none}b:after{content:'e';color:orange}b:before{content:'H';color:red}i:after,i:before{content:'l'}i:before{color:#ff0}i:after{color:#0f0}u:before{content:'o ';color:#66f}u:after{content:'W';color:blue}s{text-decoration:none}s:before{content:'o';color:#006}s:after{content:'r';color:#60f}p{display:inline}p:before{content:'l';color:#8b00ff}p:after{content:'d'}</style><b></b><i></i><u></u><s></s><p></p>
```

None of the styling is done with the markup.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 64 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Ol`HÁM Wld`Ëici%Ã$,...$BÇg`ff7fo8Þ»èç36nãr`qÍ ro0 i`¬l:#
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=JGNvbnNvbGUuY2xlYXIoKSQ&code=T2xgSMFNIFeObGRgy2ljaSXDJCwuLi4kQsdnYGZmN2ZvjTjeu%2bjnBzONNo9u43KBn2BxzSBybzAgaWCsbI46Iw) (open your browser's console)

Or, for the benefit of those on devices without browser consoles:[image]

Comment: Mfw you can’t open the console on an iPad 

Comment: Added a screenshot, @Jacob

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby

242 more procedural way:

```
require 'paint'

s = "HelloWorld"
out = ""
[
  '#FF0000',
  '#FF7F00',
  '#FFFF00',
  '#00FF00',
  "#00FFFF",
  "#5555FF",
  '#0000FF',
  '#000077',
  '#6600FF',
  '#8B00FF'
].each_with_index { |c, i| out << "#{Paint[s[i], c.dup]}" }
puts out
```

If i manage to think of a better way to generate the colours i will. A  few of the middle ones i just did some trial and error for getting the colours close.